# Timer decrease time displayed in textview with minutes and seconds

Tags: android, time, timer

I wanted to use timer to decrease 15:00 (set in textview) by each second. i.e; 14:59, 14:58 and so on...
Tried working on it but facing issue with the code. Help me to solve this

```
    Runnable updater;
void updateTime(final String timeString) {

    mTimer = (TextViewMedium) findViewById(R.id.mTimer);
    timerHandler = new Handler();

    updater = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mTimer.setText(timeString);
            timerHandler.postDelayed(updater,1000);
            Toast.makeText(JobRequestActivity.this, timeString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    };
    timerHandler.post(updater);
}
```

Comment: what issues you are facing ?

Comment: What is the `timeString` there?

Comment: timeString is the string value which i have fetched from back end. the value is 15:00.
i want to decrease this time every second

Comment: please see this 'https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer'

Answer (score 1):

The logic behind your code is wrong. Use the code below:

```
int time;
int currentTime;
Handler timerHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
        timerHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0,1000);
        currentTime-=1;
        int minutes = currentTime/60;
        int seconds = currentTime%60;
        String timeString = minutes+":"+seconds;
        TextView mTimer = (TextViewMedium) findViewById(R.id.mTimer);
        mTimer.setText(timeString);
        Toast.makeText(JobRequestActivity.this, timeString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then call the `timeHandler` anywhere in your code:

```
 time = toSeconds(yourTimeString);
 currentTime = time;
 timerHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Use this code to convert your time String to int:

```
private static int toSeconds(String s) {
    String[] mTime = s.split(":");
    int mins = Integer.parseInt(mTime[0]);
    int seconds = Integer.parseInt(mTime[1]);
    return mins*60 + seconds;
}
```

Comment: int time = 15*60; here my value is 15:00
so this cannot be initialized to int.
getting error as java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "15:00"

Comment: Edited the answer and added a method to convert your time `String`. Anyways you are expected to try and solve the minor issues.

Comment: yes. thank you the above code is working perfectly. but if i press back and start activity again then the timer is again starting with the database value.

Comment: This is a bit difficult to answer here. You can ask another question and let me know about it. Anyways, a rule of thumb is place `time` and `currentTime` variables in your `Application` class so their values change globally.

Comment: actually i have exceeded my limit today. please tell me the way how it is done. i can manage it